# Java user interface

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to create a user interface in Java for a program that grants the user the potential to build a tree of nodes, each one of them performs a specific task. The program is regarding the interface very similar to softimage ice and you can have a brief look of this by clicking on http://vimeo.com/channels/sicenetwork and watching for a while any of those short videos. You should only focus on the process of building the tree as it appears in the relevant videos. My program is based on the creation of such a tree. To this effect, except for menus and buttons, drag and drop controls are also required.

Could anyone recommend me an opportune design tool, or something in java, by the use of which I can carry out such a user interface?

Comment: How do you reckon javafx for this task?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by learning about the `JTree` here: [How to Use Trees](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Answer (score 0):

use eclipse, and Swing calls...